# How to create relationship metadata between tables without a foreign key check?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, metadata, database-agnostic

I use database metadata (primary keys, foreign keys, table names, etc), to generate code and some very complex queries. This metadata resides in the`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. I am having problems with following (simplified) use case:

#### Tables

`table A` (with `ID`)
`table B` (with `ID`, `ColumnA`, `ColumnC`)
`table C` (with `ID`)

All `ID` Columns are unique, `ColumnA` and `ColumnC` have duplicate values

#### Situation

`ColumnC` has a subset of values from `C`, in other words, `B` will never have a value that `C` doesn't.

`ColumnA` has a non-perfect superset of values from `A`, in other words, `B` has 
 exclusive values and almost all values of `A`, but `A` also rarely has exclusive values.

#### Problem

There is a Foreign Key between `B.ColumnC` referencing `C.ID`, which works as intended.

Now, because of the nature of Foreign Keys, there is no Foreign Key on `B.ColumnA` referencing `A.ID`, because `B` has values that `A` don't.

#### Question

Basically, I am having problem with some "many to many"-like relationships.

I thought about disabling Foreign Key checks and then creating a Foreign Key on `B.ColumnA`, but I haven't found a way to disable checks on only one specific contraint, because I still want to maintain data integrity on `B.ColumnC` Foreign Key.

Is there a way to create a relationship between `B` and `A` without losing data integrity and preferably without creating any additional tables or columns?

Edit: I am working with Postgres, but I will tag this with "database agnostic" to see if solutions from other vendors are portable to my case.

Comment: Would it make sense to create a foreign key from `A (id)` to `B (columnA)`? Does `B (columnA)` have unique values?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thank you for your input. Your approach makes perfect sense, I will try it and see if I can take this approach. And yes, `B.ColumnA`has duplicates while `A.ID` has unique values, I will update my question accordingly

Comment: You haven't told us the specifics of your case.  But it almost sounds as if the relationship between table B and table C is of the HAS-A variety, while the relationship between table A and table B is of the IS-A variety.

Comment: @WalterMitty I am sorry that I can't talk about the specifics. Also I tried ypercubeᵀᴹ suggestion but I found new information, I updated my question accordingly (see the Situation section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new table and proper foreign keys will likely be the more natural way to solve this.

In some DBMS (eg SQL SQL Server), you can create a disabled or disable an existing foreign key constraint with `ALTER TABLE .. NOCHECK CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE b NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [a_b_fk] ;
```

In Postgres, if you really don't want or not allowed to change the schema, you could create a foreign key from `A` to `B` and then disable the internal triggers associated with it. There is no way (as far as I know) to mark the foreign key constraint as "disabled" but disabling the internal triggers will have the desired effect.

**Create the tables**

```
blue=# create table a (id int primary key) ;
CREATE TABLE
blue=# create table b (id int primary key, aid int not null) ;
CREATE TABLE
```

**Add the foreign key constraint**

```
blue=# alter table b add constraint a_b_fk foreign key (aid) references a(id) ;
ALTER TABLE
```

**Find the trigger names**

```
blue=# SELECT tgname, tgconstraint
FROM   pg_trigger
WHERE  tgrelid = 'public.a'::regclass; 
             tgname             | tgconstraint 
--------------------------------+--------------
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_3657774 |      3657773
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_3657775 |      3657773
(2 rows)

blue=# SELECT tgname, tgconstraint
FROM   pg_trigger
WHERE  tgrelid = 'public.b'::regclass; 
             tgname             | tgconstraint 
--------------------------------+--------------
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_3657776 |      3657773
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_3657777 |      3657773
(2 rows)
```

**Disable the triggers**

```
blue=# alter table a disable trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_3657774"  ;
ALTER TABLE
blue=# alter table a disable trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_3657775"  ;
ALTER TABLE
blue=# alter table b disable trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_3657776"  ;
ALTER TABLE
blue=# alter table b disable trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_3657777"  ;
ALTER TABLE
blue=#
```

**we can now insert values as we please, the FOREIGN KEY isn't checked**

```
blue=# insert into a (id) values (1), (2), (3) ;
INSERT 0 3
blue=# insert into b (id, aid) values (1,1), (2,1), (4,4) ;
INSERT 0 3
```

**Show the tables' structure**

```
blue=# \d a
                 Table "public.a"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "a_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "b" CONSTRAINT "a_b_fk" FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES a(id)
Disabled internal triggers:
    "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_3657774" AFTER DELETE ON a FROM b NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "RI_FKey_noaction_del"()
    "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_3657775" AFTER UPDATE ON a FROM b NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "RI_FKey_noaction_upd"()

blue=# \d b
                 Table "public.b"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           | not null | 
 aid    | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "b_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "a_b_fk" FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES a(id)
Disabled internal triggers:
    "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_3657776" AFTER INSERT ON b FROM a NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "RI_FKey_check_ins"()
    "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_3657777" AFTER UPDATE ON b FROM a NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "RI_FKey_check_upd"()

blue=#
```

Comment: There's probably a clever way to identify the 4 triggers associated with a specific foreign key. I'll add an edit if I find it. (because you might have many FKs from a table and you only want to disable one of them)